# moving to jquery - broke some JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I moved some old code from another library to jQuery and in the process broke some other code. I think the way jQuery implements its `.html` function is causing me grief.

This following section is generated by an AJAX call with a success function using this syntax: `$('#status2').html(response);`

```
<!-- Section DivPlaceholders - this is required for ajax call -->
    <span id="status"></span>
    <span id="status2"> 
        <span id="response" class="response"></span>
  <table class="tableBorder">
    <tbody><tr class="row_header thin_border">
   <th class="align_left">Date</th>
 <th class="align_left">From</th>
 <th class="align_left">To</th>    
   <th class="align_left">Activity</th>
 <th class="align_left">P.Code</th>
   <th class="align_left">Del</th>
  <th class="align_left">Edit</th>
 </tr><tr>
  <!-- section: SchedResponse -->
  <tr seq="1" class="row_theme2" id="id3014201105191"></tr>
    <tr><td>20110519</td>
    <td>1330</td>
  <td>1430</td>
  <td>LUNCH</td>  
   <td></td>   

  <td><a onclick="deleteActivity(3014,20110519,1);" href="#"> <img src="img/deleteAction.png"></a></td>
  <td><a onclick="selectEditActivity(&quot;id3014201105191&quot;);" href="#"><img src="img/editAction.png"></a></td>
 </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

#### Javascript

Now I get errors on `var from_date   = cells[0].innerHTML;`

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){   
    var row = document.getElementById(pass_id), 
    seq = row.getAttribute("seq"), 
    cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");     
    var from_date   = cells[0].innerHTML;  
    var from_time   = cells[1].innerHTML;  

}
```

(thanks Paul)

Comment: why aren't you using jquery selectors? That function can be 1 line...

Comment: SLaks -- errors on *var from_date = cells[0].innerHTML;*  Error message is "cells[0] is undefined"

Comment: converting bare minimum to jquery, otherwise I'll be up all night. [[might be anyway *sigh*]. This syntax used to worked when I did Ajax calls with XUI.

Comment: think SLaks was asking what error you get, not which code produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't uses jQuery too? Try it:

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){
    var row = jQuery('#' + pass_id); // Workaround
    seq = row.attr('seq');
    cells = row.find('td');
    var from_date = cells.eq(0).html(); // better .text() I guess
    var from_time = cells.eq(1).html(); // here too
}
```

**Edit**: code fixed. Thanks to @Domenic.

Comment: Will not work; `cells[0]` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Really. I forgot that. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){   
    var row = $('#'+pass_id); 
    var seq = row.attr('seq');
    var from_date   = $('td', row).eq(0).html();  
    var from_date   = $('td', row).eq(1).html();      
}
```